# java - does setting a class equal to null get rid of all timers within that class

Tags: java, object, timer

Say I have a class called "Car", and within that class there is a timer constantly running. If I set `car=null;` will it remove the timer and any other objects within it as well?

I ask this, because I once had a class that had a timer that would create objects, and if the objects left the screen(they moved) they would be deleted. However it appeared I wasn't removing them correctly, causing there to be a ton of objects for the computer to handle which caused delay and lag. But even after I set the container class that had the timer and handled other objects within it to null, the lag would still be there, and would continue to get worse and worse, until it appeared frozen.

Answer (score 2):

No, if the timer is present and running, it will continue to run. Setting the containing object's variable to null will not change this. Note that it's simple enough to test this, since most debuggers will show you what threads are running and what the state of variables are -- so do this, run this through a debugger and see for yourself. Either a java.util.Timer or a javax.swing.Timer (you don't tell us which) will continue to run, and will use its own thread to do so

Your main problem is that you need to clean house, get rid of active objects that you no longer need, and your current plan likely won't work. For better help, help in cleaning out your unwanted objects, you're likely going to have to ask a much more complete question though, one with a [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that fully demonstrates your problem for us.

Also note that you state:

> ....handled other objects within it to null...

Please understand that you can *never* set an object to "null", and in fact that has no meaning. Yes you can set a reference variable to null, but that is something completely different, and this difference is important. It's references that matter here.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, assuming that "timer" you mentioned is java.util.Timer.

Once you created a timer, a thread is started, and will continue running until cancelled or JVM is stopped.So you need explicitly call timer.cancel() to stop timer when your "Car" is no longer used.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.

Long answer:
Assigning the `car = null;` pretty much remove the hook beetween the car object and memory peace that holds the object. If no other object have a link to that memory peace then the next time GC runs it may clear it up.

> I have a class called "Car", and within that class there is a timer constantly running.

So the timer is a static variable or a method belong to class.

If you want to remove the timer with in this class you have to explicity stop that like stop the thread that runs your timer. Or if you are running a cancellable task like [FutureTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) on java you can execute timer.cancel(true)

If you have a runnable class with a thread sleep that runs on its own thread ( this is how I create timers), then you can make a method to cancel (kill) the timer(thread)..

Answer (score -1):

If I understand this right

You have a class called Car so

```
public class Car {}
```

Inside car you have a function timer, thread based?

```
public class Car {

     public void timer() { // thread stuff to increment time }

}
```

If you call car but then free it up by declaring it null, with my understanding that class should be null. Unless if you use another class called Timer and it has it's own thread which is linked by a static function to which you call, then it should keep going on it's own since the Car class will only be using getTime(); or whatever you use to get the time. Basically saying it's independent from one another.

This was a quick reply so hopefully it answered your question

Comment: Assigning null to a **variable** (you can't "declare" a class or an object null, so please don't say this) will not free things up.

Comment: I'm stating that if you do an activity by allocating the memory for an object then attempting to discard it by calling null, it won't be removed immediately. Never stated at all that the memory would be scrubbed/freed up immediately since that is what he may be getting at =]

Comment: Again, "discard it by calling null" has no meaning for an object.